# ()=> over function() throwing me an Angular error

Tags: angularjs, function, syntax

Ok so I'm currently trying to create a registration process following a MEAN stack tutorial and I've started using ()=>{} functions over the old syntax.

Now when I used the old syntax as follows

```
    .controller('regCtrl', function(){
    this.regUser = function(){
      console.log('testing');
    };

    });
```

The code runs fine and doesn't throw me any errors in the console however when I use the new function syntax

```
.controller('regCtrl', ()=>{
  this.regUser = ()=>{
    console.log('testing');
  };
});
```

I receive this in the console log

```
angular.js:14700 TypeError: Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5055)
    at angular.js:11015
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1214)
    at angular.js:1385
    at wa (angular.js:10545)
    at q (angular.js:9934)
    at f (angular.js:9174)
    at angular.js:9039
    at angular.js:9430
    at d (angular.js:9217) "<h2 ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"
```

I'm can only assume that this an issue that is within angularjs or that I've syntaxed incorrectly however I am unable to see the issue.

My apologies if this seems like rookie mistake I'm quite an inexperienced coder.

Comment: => arrow functions (lambdas) create a lexically bound scope, so `this` is not what you are thinking it is. You need to either `.bind(this)` to the controller scope, or just use a regular anonymous function

Comment: this.regUser = return (()=>{ console.log('testing');  };) ?

Comment: @Eliseo that's not even valid

Comment: @Sterling Archer sorry, algo:()=>void;this.algo=()=>{console.log("Hola mundo")};this.algo();

Comment: @Eliseo dude, no lol

Comment: ok,I hope the code serve as a bad example :)

Answer (score 0):

arrows functions don't rebind `this` to the function scope. You shouldn't just just arrows functions because it's prettier syntax. There is a reason and when to use the. So in these 2 examples this.regUser are referring to different objects.

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used. Thus, in the following code, the
>   this within the function that is passed to setInterval has the same
>   value as this in the enclosing function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thank you Sterling and Jay for the answers much appreciated I shall read into these resources now.

Comment: no problem this is a common mistake. when it first happened to me i had a greater understanding of scoping and arrow functions afterwards